# printf format string "%a" print out the wrong msg on Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, formatting, printf, c99

The code like :   printf("%.6a", 0.1);  on the android adb shell executable will got the wrong output "a", which seems the format string "%.6a" will not be processed wisely.

The test code of executable is similar with the "hello world" demo.

file main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  printf("\n=--------------=\n");
  printf("%.6a", 0.1);
  return 0;
}
```

file Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := and_demo
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := vec_add.c 
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

the version of NDK is r9. And I have set the clags with -std=c99 to support the "%a" format string in the Android.mk file (not sure is this right). And only got a char 'a' when I run it.

How could I fix this code and let the program print the right string?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bionic (Android's "cut-down for mobile" version of libc) doesn't support the `%a` conversion specifier:

```
https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c
```

Comment: Thank you for your promptly replay. And could I link the full verson of the libc like glibc when I real need this function?